Flip bits in binary string and avoid 10 pattern
I have a binary string with bits 0 and 1 of length n. I want to flip the bits that is turn 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 in such a way that there is no substring with 10 pattern. Find the minimum number of flips needed.
Example:
Input = 10110
Output = 2
Explanation: flip bits at index 0 and 4 so string becomes 00111, here there is no substring with pattern 10
Constraints:
length of string n is 1 to 3*10^5
Here is my code:
static int solve(String s) {
  int n = s.length();
  int flips = 0;
  char[] ar = s.toCharArray();
  for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
      if(ar[i] == '1' && ar[i+1] == '0') {
      flips++;
      ar[i+1]='1'
   }
  }
  return flips;
}

Here I am checking for pattern 10, if found I am changing it to 11. But this code approach is not correct, as I need to find the minimum, so what is the correct approach to solve this problem?

leetcode 926. Flip String to Monotone Increasing. Also contains discussion. Or use your favorite search engine to find one of many explanations.

Note: you did find the minimum flips (2) for your example input (10110). You could at least provide a [mre] that shows some kind of problem in action.

This can be solved with dynamic programming.
For each index, there are two choices: make the bit 0 or 1. Instead of trying an exponential number of possibilities, we can simply track the minimum number of operations for both choices that results in a valid prefix of the binary string up to that index. Note that the choice of bit at each index depends only on the previous bit, so we have a constant time transition (and overall linear solution).
Let minOps[i][b] denote the minimum number of operations to make the prefix of the binary string up to index i valid and end in the bit b.
If the current bit is to be 0, the previous bit must also be 0.
Thus, minOps[i][0] = minOps[i - 1][0] + (1 if current bit is not 0).
For setting the current bit to 1, the previous bit could be anything (but the previous bits must be valid) as appending a 1 can never create a 10 substring in a string that did not previously contain it, so
minOps[i][1] = min(minOps[i - 1][0], minOps[i - 1][1]) + (1 if current bit is not 1).
Finally, the answer is the minimum of the two states at the last index as the last bit could be set to either 0 or 1.
We do not need to store the entire minOps array; it suffices to maintain only the previous and current state as shown in the solution below.
var minOps = new int[2];
for (char c : s.toCharArray())
    minOps = new int[]{minOps[0] + (c != '0' ? 1 : 0), 
                Math.min(minOps[0], minOps[1]) + (c != '1' ? 1 : 0)};
return Math.min(minOps[0], minOps[1]);


Thank you, can you please add some more explanation on the approach followed here.

@Anonymous I've added an explanation.

@CodeCrusader I didn't have time before, but I added an explanation now.
